# When the same object is put into multiple std::vectors, is it copied?

Tags: c++

I am an absolute C++ beginner, and just trying to get my head around some strange behaviour. Could someone please explain this to me?

I have a custom class, say

```
class Square{
public:
   bool property = false;
};

class list_of_squares{
public:
   std::vector<Square> square_list = {Square1, Square2, Square3};
   // Square1.property = false, Square2.property = true, Square3.property = false;
   std::vector<Square> second_square_list {
      for (std::size_t i = 0; i < square_list.size(); ++i) {
          if (square_list[i].property == true) {
              second_square_list.push_back(square_list[i]);
          }
      }
   }
}
```

`square_list` is just some vector of `Square` objects that I populate in some way. The idea is that if any of the `Square` objects in the vector have a particular property, I add it to a new vector `second_square_list`. I then use that second vector to do some other thing later in the code. The problem I'm finding is that if I update an object in `second_square_list`, it doesn't update the properties of the same objet in the original `square_list`. Basically, when I push back to the second square list, it seems to create a copy rather than keep the original object. How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: It does make a copy.

Comment: The answer is yes, it is copied.

Comment: *"How can I stop this from happening?"* - sounds like you want to store pointers or `std::reference_wrapper` objects int your second vector

Comment: If you don't want a copy, you can create a vector of pointers for the second vector.

Comment: Will you ever add or remove items in the `square_list` vector while the second vector exists?

Comment: @drescherjm, no. The square_list will always stay unaltered.

Comment: Then this allows you use either `std::vector<Square*> second_square_list;` or `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Square>> second_square_list;`

Comment: Another idea is to have your primary vector with objects, and the other vectors store an _index_ into the primary vector, instead of a copy of the elements themselves (or instead of storing pointers or references.)  The benefit of indices instead is that if the (primary) vector is resized (say, by adding more elements), the index of existing elements doesn't change but their address might, and pointers/references to them can be invalidated.